# Example of a non commutative ring in which all non zero elements are invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Im struggling to think of a ring that satisfies this. I thought maybe a subset of Mat$(2,\mathbb{R})$ with all elements in the General Linear group but I am not sure that would form a ring.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you are looking for a [division ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring).

Comment: The set of all invertible matrices is a group (subgroup)  of the set of all rwo by two matrices. It is therefore also a ring of the type you are searching. So you are rights choosing GL. @mcmapple

Answer (score 2):

Hamilton's quaternions.

It's that thing defined using three symbols $i,j,k$ that satisfy $i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$, which you make linear combinations with real numbers, and multiply by distributing everything and applying the rules above.

In the spirit of the start you gave, you *can* model the quaternions as a subring of $M_4(\mathbb R)$:

$a+bi+cj+dk\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}a&-b&-c&-d\\ b&a&-d&c\\ c&d&a&-b\\ d&-c&b&a\end{bmatrix}$